# Navigating through routes keeps creating observables for every ngoninit

Tags: angular, rxjs

We are trying to write a dialog box modal and we are using Rxjs for component communication in angular for reactive events. Following is the snippet

```
 public class ModelService{
    subject = new Subject();
    raiseOk(): void {
         this.subject.next({action: 'SUBMIT ... });
    }
    onOk(): Observable<any> {
       return this.subject.asObservable().pipe(
          filter(x => x.action=='SUBMIT'),
          map(x => x));
    }    
 }

 // Our modal dialog will invoke raiseOk() event when ok is clicked.

 // Assuming ModelService registered and injected into component
 export class Component{
     ngOnInit(): void{
         this.modelService.onOk().subscribe(x=> {
              console.log('ok clicked');
         });
     }
 }
```

Everything looks great. However we have identified a bug in it. What is happening, we just figured out when we switch to other route and come back to this route, we are noticing (since ngoninit is again run for component). A new observable is being created and old is still remaining.

If we switch now we have 3 observables, if we switch now we have 4 observables. The handler is firing 3 times, 4 times and more based on route switching.

I am pretty much confused because `this.http.get()` service of angular also have subscribe but it does not fire multiple times as the above does. Are we missing anything? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kill the subscription in `ngOnDestroy()`

Comment: @xyz I think its kind of a hack, I can also have a static variable and assigned to it and check for its value before creating other observable but the http service of angular does not do this way (or does it do the same behind the scenes). Is there any clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you are navigating away your subscription doesn't die.And everytime you come back to the same route, a new "subscription" is created. Kill the subscription on `ngOnDestroy()` hook.

```
export class Component{
    sub: Subscription;
    ngOnInit(): void{
        this.sub = this.modelService.onOk().subscribe(x=> {
              console.log('ok clicked');
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      if (this.sub) {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think its kind of a hack, i can also have a static variable and assigned to it but the http service of angular does not do this. Is there any clean way of doing this? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Nope, it's not a hack. See https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#ondestroy
See also section `Always subscribe!` https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-delete-request and info about cold observables.

Comment: sounds good, Just curios then how does angular does this for http services? which are injected to, does it do behind the scenes?

Comment: @user3205479: Let me check the code for `angular`. I am sure there must be some way to dispose the `observable` (get() which you are referring, if it there's a subscription for it in angular code). If they are diposing the Observable then they must be calling a `complete()` over "get()", Or some other way to complete an Observable. In your case, you don't want the `Subject` to be completed right?

Comment: Yup I dont want the subject to be completed exactly

Comment: @user3205479: Then for you `unsubscribe` is the option, it doesn't kill the observable, just removes the listener.

Comment: @MarcinArmatys: Thank you for the links!